# Regex: How to negate a set of word from being following a word?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I want regex that matches `default-src` followed by a space BUT NOT followed by any of the following words (including quotes): 'unsafe-inline', or 'unsafe-eval', or `\s\*\s`. The last is a `*` (preceeded or followed by a space)

I tried this but is not correct:

```
default-src\\s(?!'unsafe-inline'|?!'unsafe-eval'|?!(\\s\*\\s))
```

In fact I do not know how to negate a set of words. Any help?

Example of string that should not match:

```
default-src 'unsafe-inline'
```

Example of a string that match:

```
default-src x.example
```

Comment: Why is the `?!.*` if the `default-src` should be followed by space only?

Comment: This: `"default-src\s(?!.*(?:'unsafe-inline'|'unsafe-eval'|\s\*\s))" ` does not return anything.

Comment: @None: The regex you seem to be looking is [`default-src(?!(?:\s*('?)(?:unsafe-inline|unsafe-eval)\1| +\* +))\s`](https://regex101.com/r/38w30t/1/)

Comment: Try [`default-src\s(?!('?)unsafe-(?:inline|eval)\1|\s*\*\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/7lZdK0/1)

Comment: You're only wrong at lookahead syntax other than that rules are well defined.

Comment: `...(?!.*(?:word1|word2|word3...))` is a generic example that answers the title question. *How to negate a set of word from being following a word?* -> `word(?!.*(set|of|words))`. `.*` makes it fail if the set of words is not following the `word` *immediately*. To solve the problem with parsing code you need the language code parser, a single regex might help with the immediate task as a work around, but will not be a solution.

Comment: What is \1 for??

Comment: @revo Sorry The regex matches this: `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` but it should not. How can I add that there might be any string (with/without quotes and may contain any characters that allowed in URLs) before before or after `'unsafe-inline'`

Comment: See it here https://regex101.com/r/7lZdK0/4